# Reindexing using NEST V5.4 - ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, nest, reindex

I'm quite new to ElasticSearch. I'm trying to reindex a index in order to rename it. I'm using NEST API v5.4. 
I saw this example:

```
var reindex =
    elasticClient.Reindex<Customer>(r =>
        r.FromIndex("customers-v1")
            .ToIndex("customers-v2")
            .Query(q => q.MatchAll())
            .Scroll("10s")
            .CreateIndex(i =>
                i.AddMapping<Customer>(m =>
                    m.Properties(p =>
                        p.String(n => n.Name(name => name.Zipcode).Index(FieldIndexOption.not_analyzed))))));
```

**Source**: http://thomasardal.com/elasticsearch-migrations-with-c-and-nest/

However, I can't reproduce this using NEST 5.4. I think that is to version 2.4. 
I check the breaking changes of ElasticSearch and try reindexing using this:

**Source**: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/nest-breaking-changes.html

```
public method Nest.ReindexDescriptor..ctor Declaration changed (Breaking)
2.x: public .ctor(IndexName from, IndexName to) 5.x: public .ctor()

var reindex = new client.Reindex(oldIndexName, newIndexName);
```

But this did not work too.
I also search for documentation but i didn't find any code on c#, just JSON 
**Source**: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html)

**Can someone give me a example how to reindex using NEST 5.4 on C#?**

Thanks in advance! :slight_smile:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After search for 2 long days I found out the solution to reindex a index. In order to solve future problems, I'll provide my solution.

Nest Version - 5.4

```
var reindex = client.Reindex<object>(r => r
              .BackPressureFactor(10)
              // ScrollAll - Scroll all the documents of the index and store it for 1minute 
              .ScrollAll("1m", 2, s => s
                  .Search(ss => ss
                      .Index(oldIndexName)
                          .AllTypes())
                      // there needs to be some degree of parallelism for this to work
                      .MaxDegreeOfParallelism(4))
              .CreateIndex(c => c
                  // New index here
                  .Index(newIndexName)
                  .Settings(
                      // settings goes here)
                  .Mappings(
                      // mappings goes here))
              .BulkAll(b => b
                  // New index here!
                  .Index(newIndexName)
                  .Size(100)
                  .MaxDegreeOfParallelism(2)
                  .RefreshOnCompleted()));
```

the ReIndex method returns a cold **IObservable** on which you have to call **.Subscribe()** to kick off everything.

So, you need to add it to your code:

```
var o = new ReindexObserver(
            onError: (e) => { //do something },
            onCompleted: () => { //do something });
reindex.Subscribe(o);
```

**Useful links to check this are:**

[Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/blog/nest-5-0-released)

[Issue 2660 on GitHub](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/2660)

[Issue 2771 on GitHub](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/2771)

Comment: Glad you found it in the end NatsuDragonEye! We also expose `.Wait(TimeSpan, onNext; (x)=>)` helpers if you need to block on them.

Comment: If ElasticSearch could add more information about this topic on NEST API would be great.